# Setting UIDatePicker countDownTimer default value to 1 minute

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uidatepicker

I have a `UIDatePicker` with `countDownTimer` mode in my app.

I want the default date to be `0 hours, 1 minute`. I've tried to do that by adding the line:

`self.datePicker.date = Date()`

but the result was the current time in a timer format. For example, if the time is 10:55am the timer shows `10 hours, 55 minutes`.

How can I set the timer default value to `0 hours, 1 minute`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to set the `countDownDuration` property. As the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker/1615986-countdownduration) say,

> Use this property to get and set the currently selected value when the date picker’s mode property is set to countDownTimer.

```
pickerView.countDownDuration = 60
```